# update to python 3.7 using anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, python-3.7

[Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html) alpha version is out, but I haven't been able to find any post on how to update to python 3.7 using Anaconda - maybe they will wait for the official release? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Python 3.7 is now available to be installed, but many packages have not been updated yet. As noted by [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51105868/2449192), there is a GitHub issue tracking the progress of Anaconda building all the updated packages.

---

Until someone creates a conda package for Python 3.7, you can't install it. Unfortunately, something like 3500 packages show up in a search for "python" on Anaconda.org (https://anaconda.org/search?q=%22python%22) so I couldn't see if anyone has done that yet.

You might be able to build your own package, depending on what OS you want it for. You can start with the recipe that conda-forge uses to build Python: https://github.com/conda-forge/python-feedstock/

In the past, I think Continuum have generally waited until a stable release to push out packages for new Pythons, but I don't work there, so I don't know what their actual policy is.

Comment: There are no Python 3.7 release candidate packages (as of May 4th 2018), neither in default channels nor in conda-forge channel. You can use "conda search python=3.7" to search for any Python packages with version numbers starting with "3.7" (which includes stable releases as well as betas or release candidates, if there are any; compare what  "conda search python=3.6" reports)

Comment: The latest miniconda has a 3.7 python in it https://conda.io/miniconda.html

Comment: Suppose I have 3.6 already installed. If I do "conda install -c anaconda python=3.7". Then, does the install command install 3.7 version along-side existing python (I have 3.6 existing) or does it upgrade the existing (3.6) to 3.7?

Comment: It upgrades. You can check this by running the command with the `--dry-run` option.

Answer (score 88):

This can be installed via conda with the command `conda install -c anaconda python=3.7` as per https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python.

Though not all packages support 3.7 yet, running `conda update --all` may resolve some dependency failures.

Comment: You can also create an environment called `py37` using this command: `conda create -n py37 -c anaconda python=3.7`. However I cannot seem to install other packages such as numpy/jupyter, using `conda install`. Dependency checks prevent it. Installation works using `pip install numpy jupyter`.

Comment: The dependencies are not currently correctly configured for 3.7.  This is an issue that should be shortly resolved and can be tracked here: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9686

Comment: I get errors when I try this: UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - python 3.7*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package. I did do an update of conda and then did conda info python=3.7 and it listed this strange "vc *14" and pip which is of course installed.  Does anyone know if  there is a place to report this to Anaconda?

Comment: @RichMeister the above link in my previous comment is the the appropriate issue tracker. The issue you’re experiencing has already been reported.

Comment: @mcguip Hi, Since that one  I now have more issues.  For some reason I'm getting a huge list of conflicts now - on one system. On another I was able to get Python 3.7 "installed" via conda but I can't get to it with "conda create" and I need that to be able to run it under Jupyter.  I thought there was some kind of "path to the python.exe file" spec like -p or something but now I can't find it.

Comment: @mcguip Hi,  Re:  more issues - now fixed.   I had a huge list of dependency errors.  I did a conda update --all and now 3.7 installs.

Comment: @n1k31t4 - great tip.  I found I could install other packages once I did a 'source activate py37'.  Installing a newer python into a specific environment necessitates this.  Maybe your ran into a different conflict, but thought I would point it out.

Comment: Suppose I have 3.6 already installed. If I do "conda install -c anaconda python=3.7". Then, does the install command install 3.7 version along-side existing python (I have 3.6 existing) or does it upgrade the existing (3.6) to 3.7?

Comment: @variable I am using Conda Python on a Windows 10 machine. I wanted to upgrade my current environment py3 from python 3.6 to python 3.7. What I did is simply (1) `conda activate py3`, then (2) as @mcguip suggested, type `conda install -c anaconda python=3.7`. That's all. You can type `python --version` to check the updated version. Under py3 environment folder, python3.6 no longer exists.

Comment: Note that you need to run `conda update -n root conda` before running `conda update --all`. This is because conda needs to be the latest version before attempting to update all packages.

Answer (score 24):

To see just the Python releases, do `conda search --full-name python`.

Answer (score 18):

The [September 4th release for 3.7](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/python-3-7-package-build-out-miniconda-release/) recommends the following:

```
conda install python=3.7 anaconda=custom
```

If you want to create a new environment, they recommend:

```
conda create -n example_env numpy scipy pandas scikit-learn notebook
anaconda-navigator
conda activate example_env
```

Answer (score 6):

run conda navigator, you can upgrade your packages easily in the friendly GUI

Answer (score 4):

```
conda create -n py37 -c anaconda anaconda=5.3
```

seems to be working.