# Error installing Python 3.7 with Anaconda

Tags: python, error-handling, anaconda, python-3.7

Note: I am aware that this is very similar to what is on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939562/update-to-python-3-7-using-anaconda), but it is distinct in that I know it should now be possible, but I'm experiencing a problem that someone else mentioned on a comment of an answer, but not in any answers

Three days ago Python 3.7 was released to download in the raw, and yesterday it became available on Anaconda. Between Anaconda's [Manage Python](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html) and [Managing Environments](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) pages, I was able to determine what to do, but continued to get the error

`UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - python=3.7
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.`

`conda info python=3.7` told me

`dependencies:
    vc 14.*
    pip`

I tried updating/installing both `vc` and `pip`, already being sure that at least `pip` can't be lacking, and it confirmed, `# All requested packages already installed.`

Has anyone successfully installed Python 3.7 with Anaconda yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last post here by mingwandroid seems to answer the question:
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9686

You have to wait until Anaconda is released for python 3.7 (NOT just the python 3.7 package, but the whole of Anaconda), or install only python 3.7 in a separate environment.  (I haven’t attempted the latter, but note that even that is possible at this point only for a subset of os platforms, and I also wouldn’t be surprised if there were hiccups with existing installations—I would recommend waiting until the new Anaconda for 3.7 is released).

Comment: Thank you, now it looks like `vc` may not be available for Python 3.7 yet, and this problem is not only found in Windows but also in Mac and Linux.