# Conda environment with Python 3.7, pandas, and scikit-learn (Windows 10) - dependencies error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dependencies, conda, environment

I am trying to set up an environment with python 3.7, pandas and scikit-learn to test if my code is compatible with 3.7. But I am having a hard time making sense of the error messages I run into. I am working on Windows 10 64-bit

When I run

```
conda create --name Py37Test python=3.7 pandas scikit-learn
```

I get this error message

```
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - python=3.7
  - scikit-learn -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0']
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

but when I run

```
conda info scikit-learn
```

it says:

```
dependencies:
mkl >=2018.0.0
numpy >=1.11.3,<2.0a0
python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0
scipy
vc 14.*
```

Similarly, if I run

```
conda create --name Py37Test python=3.7 pandas
```

I get the error:

```
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - pandas -> python-dateutil -> six
  - pandas -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0']
  - python=3.7
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
    enter code here
```

And when I then run

```
conda info pandas
```

I get

```
dependencies:
    numpy >=1.11.3,<2.0a0
    python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0
    python-dateutil >=2.5.*
    pytz
    vc 14.*
```

Which again seems to imply that dependencies are OK.

Help?!

**Update:**
Running

```
>conda create --name Py37Test python=3.7 pandas=0.23.1 scikit-learn=0.19.1
```

gives:

```
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - python=3.7
  - scikit-learn=0.19.1 -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0']
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Comment: Well, this isn't a duplicate, but it does have the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46939562/2449192, namely, that these packages aren't available for Python 3.7 yet. That's what the dependencies output means, it's only available for 3.6 (why it lists 2.7 as the requirement, I'm not sure, but the other output is pretty clear)

Comment: Python 3.7 is no longer in alpha as in October, when that question was asked. It actually looks like that pandas and scikit-learn aren't available on conda as pointed out in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46960195/7298955. What really confuses me is why it lists Python 2 as a requirement, as you say... Thanks anyway.

Comment: Is the anaconda you downloaded (and in it `conda`) compatible with python 3.7?

Comment: It is the most up to date Anacona/conda, and I can definitely create a Python 3.7 environment. I am afraid that, unfortunately, @darthbith is right. It is just the requirement message that is confusing.