# How to install Conda 3.7 environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

Just installed Anaconda on my Mac and tried to create virtual environment with it:
`conda create -n py37 python=3.7 anaconda`

Got error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - anaconda -> alabaster==0.7.10=py27h9dd7d6e_0 -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0']
  - anaconda -> distribute==0.6.45=py26_0
  - anaconda -> libedit==3.1=hb4e282d_0
  - anaconda -> wheel==0.29.0=py27h84bd1c0_1
  - anaconda -> xz==5.2.3=ha24016e_1
  - python=3.7
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Anyone has idea what to try to fix this?

Comment: Well, this isn't a duplicate, but it does have the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46939562/2449192, namely, that these packages aren't available for Python 3.7 yet. That's what the dependencies output means, it's only available for 3.6. Not sure why it pics Python 2.7 as the conflict, but the answer is the same

Comment: @darthbith Thanks. So I should try `conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda` ?

Comment: Yes, all the packages are available for 3.6