# Is there support for Python 3.8 in Conda? (I need sqlite 3.25 w/ Window Functions)

Tags: python, sqlite, conda

I'm attempting to use Python 3.8 to access SQLite 3.25, which now supports Window Functions.

I've already attempted to install python 3.8 via conda create, but it says the repo is not found.

From what I've read, SQLite 3.25 is the first to support Window Functions, which I need. I would also preferably like to install with Python using conda create... is there a link for this?

Comment: Why do you need Python 3.8 to access SQLite 3.25? In any case, you can search for Python 3.8, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48425331/2449192

Comment: Possible duplicate of [update to python 3.7 using anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939562/update-to-python-3-7-using-anaconda)